# EKS using ALB, connecting TargetGroupBinding and TargetGroup

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, aws-application-load-balancer

I have service, like this below.

```
$kubectl get services             
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
apa000ser    ClusterIP   10.100.251.247   <none>        80/TCP    2m42s
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.100.0.1       <none>        443/TCP   145m
```

and deployment also works well and found the pods working.

```
$get deployment 
NAME        READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
apa000dep   1/1     1            1           92m

$kubectl get pods      
NAME                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
apa000dep-84d9f4dbf8-ch76f   1/1     Running   0          96m
```

Then I deploy `targetgroup.yaml` with existing `targetGroupARN`

```
apiVersion: elbv2.k8s.aws/v1beta1
kind: TargetGroupBinding
metadata:
  name: my-tgb
spec:
  serviceRef:
    name: apa000ser 
    port: 80
  targetGroupARN: arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:ap-northeast-1:67810XXXXXXX:targetgroup/myingress/9bfc8fadbe09680d
  targetType: ip
```

deployment is successful.

```
kubectl apply -f targetgroup.yml 
targetgroupbinding.elbv2.k8s.aws/my-tgb created
```

In my understanding, pods should appear in the AWS console automatically, but they are not.

Where am I wrong? What am I missing?

[image]

---

Update.

I checked the service `apa000ser` ip and registered this manually in target group,`172.31.0.143 port 80`, It works, even though there is only one ip in target.

How is this different to using `targetgroupbinding` ?

```
$kubectl describe service apa000ser        
Name:              apa000ser
Namespace:         default
Labels:            <none>
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app=apa000kube
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Family Policy:  SingleStack
IP Families:       IPv4
IP:                10.100.251.247
IPs:               10.100.251.247
Port:              <unset>  80/TCP
TargetPort:        80/TCP
Endpoints:         172.31.0.143:80
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

[image]

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out? I am also trying to use TargetGroupBinding bu no luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to expose a service, you should be using NodePort not ClusterIP.

Also, verify you are using the right Target Type and if you need to configure the node selectors, you can find the information about it [here](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.6/guide/targetgroupbinding/targetgroupbinding/)